# How to add dynamic font shorthand properties in scss with @mixin?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

```
@mixin title($cat-font: 12px, $line-height: 18px) {
        font: normal $cat-font/$line-height 'Open Sans', serif;
}

a.title{
  @include title();
}
```

If you write `$cat-font/$line-height`, slash "/" will be division operator and you will see in the css is:

```
a.title{
   font: normal 0.6667 'Open Sans', serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reference for font shorthand for scss.
https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-basics-operators/

The solution is

```
@mixin title($cat-font: 12px, $line-height: 18px) {
        font: normal #{$cat-font} / #{$line-height} 'Open Sans', serif;
}

a.title{
  @include title();
}
```

You will see in the css is:

```
a.title{
   font: normal 12px/18px 'Open Sans', serif;
}
```

**Reference:**

```
font-size: 16px / 24px // Outputs as CSS

    font-size: (16px / 24px) // Uses parentheses, does division

    font-size: #{$base-size} / #{$line-height}; // Uses interpolation, outputs as CSS

    font-size: $base-size / $line-height // Uses variables, does division

    opacity: random(4) / 5; // Uses a function, does division

    padding-right: 2px / 4px + 3px // Uses an arithmetic expression, does division
```